# Old Computer Having No Video Output Or Beeping On Boot

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard

I have gotten an old computer from my technical institute teacher.
I checked inside, everything seems to be in order, the power supplies are plugged up. But when I turn on the computer, it gives no output to the monitor.

I know it's not the monitor with the problem, as I checked with many different ones, and I checked by plugging my laptop into it and it works fine. I've tried looking online for information, but this particular computer seems to be no where on the internet besides an outdated TigerDirect.com page.

When I got this computer it didn't have everything it came with, but there should be enough to at least get to the BIOS, but no video output. I've tried plugging and unplugging the dvd, hard drive, and even tried resetting the motherboard by pulling out the battery for 10ish minutes.

Please help me fix this.

---

**Current Computer Info:**

- Model: Visionman GMI-1NG701 Intel Gaming PC
- Processor: Intel Pentium Dual Core E2180
- Ram: 1GB
- Graphics: Integrated Graphics

---

Edit 1:

> Have any photos?

They aren't the highest quality, but here you go:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Have any photos? Ram? CPU? Is there an onboard speaker, maybe it needs one? Jumpers & important equipment was removed/changed before you got it? Reset the bios?

Comment: @Xen2050 i added some images. they arent the highest quality.

Comment: Looks like there's a CPU & ram at least, maybe a little speaker (they're sometimes black cylinders with a hole on top), no video card so it could be a jumper (if there are any) not letting it use the onboard video, taking the battery out should've reset the bios. Maybe there's multiple video outputs, like VGA/DVI/HDMI & only one works. Do the fans all turn on, any lights anywhere turn on or flash, even on the keyboard? Maybe something's just broken, could try different power/ram or moving the ram to the other slot... The teacher said it was working when you got it?

Comment: One thing that goes bad over time is the CMOS/BIOS battery. Another possibility is electrolytic capacitors, particularly in the power supply. Check voltages on the PS under load.

Comment: Note: your link is useless. It shows me just "Your order requires additional verification by phone. Please call..."

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski which is why i said outdated.

Comment: @Xen2050 Theres only VGA, the fans and lights come on fine. the disk drive also makes noises. And the teacher said it should work fine.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Ill get back to you but i dont think thats so because the lights turn on fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a piezo speaker, so that would be the source of a lack of beeps of any kind, be it a beep code or otherwise.

A search for the model brings up a page stating 2GB of Ram and a Nvidia 9600GT(512Mb).  This machine has clearly been raided for parts in the past.

The most likely scenario (other than DOA) is that the BIOS has been set-up (and defaults) to using external video only.  As you no longer have a graphics card installed, there is no (enabled) video output.

Two options here; force a BIOS reset, and to try a graphics card.

- The graphics card is the simplest to try, if you have one to hand, or a friend has one.  Plug it in, turn it on, hope for the best.
- On the assumption that there isn't a dedicated BIOS reset clearly marked, to reset the BIOS (you said you had pulled the battery, but not that you had pulled the power.  Just in case):

  - unplug the power to the machine, and remove the cell battery
  - press the power button.  This will drain most, if not all of the important capacitors of their charge.  This will in turn cause the BIOS to be reset (it requires power to keep the current settings stored).
  - Plug in the machine and turn it on.  hope for the best.

It is possible for similar symptoms to occur following actual damage.  I recently tried to fix a machine with similar symptoms.  In this case it was probably killed by ESD, and neither the processor or motherboard would work, even when all other components were replaced and they were tested individually.  The symptoms were the same as seen here, it powered up but then did nothing.

If a graphics card / bios reset does not fix the problem, you may be best off returning the computer to your teacher, and asking for any money you spent on it back.  I would doubt that it worked when you received it, or that it can be fixed without basically buying a new computer.

It is old hardware anyway,  unless you explicitly need Windows/x86 you would probably be better off with a Raspberry Pi or another cheap (modern) computer.

Comment: Yeah, i wasnt expecting it to work, but i like to mess with old hardware and maybe get it fixed up. if the motherboard was having an issue i was just gonna salvage the ram and use the case for a new computer. And yes the graphics card was removed & 1 ram stick but it has onboard graphics so it should work fine. Also the computer was given to me for free as it was gonna be thrown away. also also I always unplug the computer before I mess with the insides

Comment: I'd +1, but a raspberry pi != desktop/server performance. Didn't find a good comparison but some redditors say a 6 year old "Celeron will curb stomp any of the Pis on the market"

Comment: @Mcclures yes, unplugging is always a good idea.  Just making sure as it wouldn't be the first time I have tried to talk someone through this and finding that they missed that step.  Always pays to be explicit :)

Comment: @Xen2050 there are other considerations.  Power usage will be much lower for one, and a Pi3 is perfectly capable of doing almost any typical task, be it surfing the web, writing documents or watching videos.  It won't be a good gaming platform, but neither is the listed PC.  OP didn't state much about the situation, so if it was old pc because cheap, I was giving another option that is also cheap and would let them do school work (assumption based on PC from teacher)